# Reducing number of calls to the methods of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I was interested in a way to reduce the number of calls to the injectMethod on the below constructor function:

```
function InjectScriptsAndExecute(url) {
 this.url = url;
 this.injectMethod = function() {
  var inject = $.ajax({
       url: this.url,
       cache: true,
       dataType: 'script'
       }); 
  return inject;     
 }
}
var pngFix = new InjectScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js");
var pngList = new InjectScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js");
pngFix.injectMethod();
pngList.injectMethod();
```

Is there a way i can pass an object to the constructor function that contains as many URL references as i like without having to declare a new variable and subsequently call the method?

Comment: As a side note, instead of doing `this.injectMethod = function(){...`, you should really reuse that function by making adding it to the `prototype` of `InjectScriptsAndExecute()`. No need to construct a new function for each instance. So after the constructor, but before you create any instances, do `InjectScriptsAndExecute.prototype.injectMethod = function() {...`, then remove that method from the constructor.

Comment: @RyanP13: Just more efficient. Say if you call the constructor with `new` 100 times. You've created a separate (yet identical) function for each instance. By adding the function to the `prototype`, whether you create 1 or 1,000 instances, there will only be the one function that they all share.

Comment: Thanks.  Just been dipping my toes in OOJS and have the unnerving feeling i am about to fall in head first :)

Comment: This approach does not leav much actually in the original constructor but i guess that is the whole point?  To allow for extension?

Comment: @RyanP13: The `prototype` property relies on there being a constructor. You'll only get the benefit of sharing that function (in that manner) by creating a `new` instance of the class. The function is still very much part of the class. Hard to say if an OO approach is the best here. If you don't really have much need for the resulting instance, except to immediately call the `injectMethod` function, then I guess I'd roll the entire functionality into a simple method that you call, which makes the AJAX call for you.

Comment: Thanks again.  It is really just experimentation on my part.  I started off with this http://jsfiddle.net/TtUJW/ and just wanted to see if i could do it differently.

Comment: @RyanP13: Good idea. Always good to experiment. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the constructor receive an object or array, but you're still only creating one instance.

One way around it would be to modify the constructor so that you call it as a regular function (without `new`), and pass it an Array of the urls. Then it will iterate over the array, making a recursive call, but *with* the `new` keyword, and overwriting each url with the new instance.

Then it would return the original Array.

```
function InjectScriptsAndExecute(url) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(url).indexOf('Array') != -1) {
        for (var i = 0, len = url.length; i < len; i++) {
            url[i] = new InjectScriptsAndExecute(url[i]);
        }
        return url;
    } else {
        this.url = url;
        this.injectMethod = function() {
            var inject = $.ajax({
                url: this.url,
                cache: true,
                dataType: 'script'
            });
            return inject;
        }
    }
}
var arr = InjectScriptsAndExecute(["/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js",
                       "/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js"
                       ]);
var len = arr.length;

while( len-- ) {
    arr[len].injectMethod();
}
```

For safety, you would really want to have some additional checks to see if the function is being called as the constructor or not. And you'd want to have appropriate behavior for each depending on whether it received an Array or a String.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* -- but you're going to get into interesting territory here:

```
function InjectScriptsAndExecute() {
 this.urls = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
 this.injectMethod = function() {
  for (var i=0; i < this.urls.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
       url: this.urls[i],
       cache: true,
       async: false, // Otherwise you cannot depend on the parse order
       dataType: 'script'
       });
 }
}

// You can then use it in this way:
var all_scripts = 
new InjectScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js",
        "/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js");

all_scripts.injectMethod();
```

What you probably want is a dependency manager like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [LAB.js](http://labjs.com/) if you're doing this with any frequency.  [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org) and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) also provide dependency management, if you're looking for a full framework.