# Performance of OOJS over functional JavaScript programming

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, object, functional-programming

This question relates to a previous question here:

[Reducing number of calls to the methods of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617055/reducing-number-of-calls-to-the-methods-of-a-javascript-object)

When profiling these two code snippets with Firebug:

```
function ie6PNGFixLoader(scriptURL) {
    if(arguments.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            $.ajax({// load PNG fix scripts
                url: arguments[i],
                cache: true,
                dataType: 'script'
            });
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }               
}

var pngFix = "/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js";    
var pngList = "/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js"; 
ie6PNGFixLoader(pngFix, pngList);
```

and

```
function InjectScriptsAndExecute(url) {
    this.url = url;
}

InjectScriptsAndExecute.prototype.InjectMethod = function() {
    var inject = $.ajax({
                        url: this.url,
                        cache: true,
                        dataType: 'script',
                        async: false, // Otherwise you cannot depend on the parse order
                        }); 
    return inject;  
}
var pngFix = new InjectScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js");
var pngList = new InjectScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js");
pngFix.InjectMethod();
pngList.InjectMethod();
```

It appers that the latter's calls to the InjectScriptsAndExecute method are much faster than the former's calls to its function.  A colleague has asked me why when i mentioned the performance improvement but i cannot explain it myself.

Any advice for better understanding would be greatfully received.

Comment: You're going to have to post more information about your performance measurements. The primary difference between those is not the coding style (which will make almost no measurable difference) but the differing setup of the ajax operations (async vs. synchronous).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments is **not** `Array` it's an `Object` that somewhat behaves like an array.

```
if(arguments.length > 0) { // Slow AND superfluous
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { // Even SLOWER
        arguments[i]; // Holy...
```

**Cache** the length, accessing the property is slow, IE6 won't have no optimization at all for `.length` and I even suspect it to be really slow when using the `arguments[i]` since it is not a real `Array` and might therefore do an unoptimized property lookup.

If you want to get the best of both worlds, pass a normal `Array`, use a plain `for` loop, and `cache` the `length`.

```
function ie6PNGFixLoader(scripts) {
    for (var i = 0, l = scripts.length; i < l; i++) {
        $.ajax({// load PNG fix scripts
            url: scripts[i],
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'script'
        });
    }              
}

ie6PNGFixLoader(["/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js",
                 "/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js"]);
```

**EDIT**

To make it clear, timing the loop is useless, the request is async, all you do is timing a loop and a call to `$.ajax` there's no point in optimizing here, especially not for **two** entries. Even in IE6, doing the Ajax call itself (even just calling `$.ajax`) will be way slower then the loop.

Comment: @Anders so what, and why the downvote? Care to post more than a giant performance test that has not a word about `arguments` in it?

Comment: @Anders And if you're complaining about the fact I did not recommend `while(--i)`, and could have just as well ranted about premature optimization in my answer, and all I said was `if you want the best of both words`. Besides that, the loop is hardly the limiting factor here... the Ajax will take way more time.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, I only posted a link about loop conditions and it's performance since you were talking about it. Thought it might be useful information for the OP.

Comment: +1.  While you can do convoluted things like `while(--i)` or `for (i=0; node = array[i++];)` and gain a tiny fraction of a micro-second, you lose the most important thing, readability.  The `for` loop shown by @Ivo is clean, readable and understood by just about every single developer on the planet.  There's no sense micro-optimizing that readability away unless it's absolutely positively necessary.  And since the `$.ajax` call will dominate anyway, it's a moot point.

Comment: Oh and another thing coming to mind if you need to iterate in forward order the `while(--i)` is useless.